# ansible remote script execution's log in local machine

Tags: python, ansible

I have python script which basically do verification of installed services in remote machine.This script will run in remote machine and I am using ansible to call this script.I having trouble in logging the script in to a file in local machine.

**test.yml (Ansible)**

```
      - name: Verifying route ,run script to analyse temp_route.txt file
        script: /scripts/verify.py {{ prox1 }},{{ ip }} {{ ip }}
        register: output
```

**verify.py**

```
#from pprint import pprint
logging.basicConfig(filename='script/logs/install.log',format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s', datefmt='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y', level=logging.INFO)

def func1():
    ----do something
    logging.info('%s %s',key, value)
```

All our script uses this way of logging ....other than this all script run locally.Only this one runs on remote machine.

While running the script i get ansible error path not found.It seems it is searching path in remote machine which is not available

**UPDATED**

I have machine A where all the script runs and I am launching a vm from that machine and configuring it using ansible. I have log file called install.log.
All the other script output the log in this file.I want my verify.py which will run on remote should also output log in install.log file

Is this possible to do it through ansible ?

Comment: can you use absolute path for logging? this may cause the issue

Answer (score 0):

The [script module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) copies a script that is local to the Ansible machine and copies it to the remote node and then executes it.

If you want to execute a script that is already on the remote node then you could instead use either the [command](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html) or [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) modules to trigger the script.

Alternatively you could first use a [fetch](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html) task to retrieve the file from the remote node and then use the script task to copy it back and then execute it. I'm struggling to think of a reason to do it this way rather than via a command/shell task though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way of writing to a log file on a local machine from a script Ansible runs - Ansible copies the script over through its SSH connection, then executes it from the remote host.

As @ydaetskcoR says in their answer, one solution is to write the log to a remote file and use the fetch module to retrieve it.

Another option is to change the script to print log messages to stdout and stderr, then access the information that would have gone into a log from there - from the `output` variable you registered, you'd be able to access the contents with `debug: var=output.stdout_lines`, evaluate a conditional against the script's return code with `output.rc`, and more.